# How can I determine the height and depth of a "multi-line" `\ooalign`?

Tags: dimensions, height

How can I determine the height and depth of a "multi-line" `\ooalign`?

```
\ooalign{\relax\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip-2ex}X\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip+2ex}\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip+1ex}X\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip-1ex}%
        }%
```

With the answers to [Depth and height confusion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/124811/6865) I seem to get just the dimensions of the lower part of the `\ooalign`.

Comment: If I recall, this the height/depth is dependent on the first/last elements. Your first and last have no height/depth.

Comment: @Werner: Yes, when trying to measure this, it is indeed 0pt large, but when printed it is not, of course. Thus I would like to know the height of the "inked area".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Analysis

`\ooalign` uses `\vtop`. If the first element is a box, then its height becomes the height of `\ooalign`, otherwise the height is 0 pt.
Without `\noalign` at the start of `\ooalign`, the first element is the first row, then `\ooalign` has the height of the first row. In this case the row is empty (`\relax`), thus the height is 0 pt.

The depth is more complicate. TeX first sets the contents of `\vtop` in a `\vbox`. Then TeX gets the height as described above and moved the reference point accordingly. Thus the depth is the total height of the `\vbox` minus the height from above.

Because of the paragraph parameter settings, the rows in `\ooalign` do not move their reference points, thus the rows overwrite the previous rows. Therefore only the last depth and the sum of the contributions of `\noalign` are having an effect for the overall depth. In this case, the sum of the `\noalign{\vskip...}` contributions is 0 pt as well as the depth of the last row. Thus the depth of the `\ooalign` is 0 pt.

## Macro `\charsovereachother` (without `\noalign`)

The following macro `\charsovereachother` can be used instead of `\ooalign`, when the user wants to have the height and depth as maximum of all rows in `\ooalign`. (Makes only sense without manual movements via `\noalign{\vskip...}`).

The test file is written for plain TeX, but the macro can also be used in LaTeX:

```
\edef\RestoreAtCatcode{\catcode`\noexpand\@=\the\catcode`\@\relax}
\catcode`\@=11
\newdimen\COEO@height
\newdimen\COEO@depth
\begingroup\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
\expandafter\ifx\csname protected\endcsname\relax
\else
  \expandafter\protected
\fi 
\def\charsovereachother#1{%
  \leavevmode
  \begingroup
    \setbox0\vtop{%
      \baselineskip0pt\relax
      \lineskip0pt\relax
      \lineskiplimit=-16383.99999pt\relax
      \gdef\COEO@height{0pt}%
      \gdef\COEO@depth{0pt}%
      \everycr{}\tabskip0pt\halign{%
        % the cell contents is measured and
        % the maximum values for height and depth are remembered
        \setbox0\hbox{##}%
        \ifdim\COEO@height<\ht0 %
          \xdef\COEO@height{\the\ht0}%
        \fi
        \ifdim\COEO@depth<\dp0 %
          \xdef\COEO@depth{\the\dp0}%
        \fi
        \unhcopy0 %
        \crcr
        #1%
        \crcr
      }%
    }%  
    \vtop{%
      % update the height if necessary
      \ifdim\COEO@height>\ht0 %
        \hrule width0pt height\COEO@height depth0pt %
        \kern-\ht0 %
      \fi
      \unvcopy0 %
      % update the depth if necessary
      \ifdim\COEO@depth>\dp0 %
        \kern-\dp0 %
        \kern\COEO@depth
      \fi   
    }%
  \endgroup
}%
\RestoreAtCatcode

% Test

\hrule

\ooalign{a. row$_{\hbox{(1st line)}}$\hfill\cr
  \kern10em last row$^{\hbox{(2nd line)}}$}

\hrule

\bigskip

\hrule  

\charsovereachother{a. row$_{\hbox{(1st line)}}$\hfill\cr
  \kern10em last row$^{\hbox{(2nd line)}}$}

\hrule

\bye
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: +1 and thanks for the explanation of what is happening (instead of just giving a solution)!

Answer (score 2):

Heiko's `\charsovereachother` can be directly emulated with a properly configured `\Longstack` from the `stackengine` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\cr}\setstackgap{L}{0pt}\def\stackalignment{l}
\begin{document}
\hrule  

\Longstack{a. row$_{\hbox{(1st line)}}$\hfill\cr
  \kern10em last row$^{\hbox{(2nd line)}}$}

\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the `\hfill` can be eliminated from the argument, but I left it there to match the argument used by Heiko.

Note also that `\vskip`s are not permitted in the stacking arguments, but can be simulated in other ways, depending on the problem.  For example, the MWE of the OP is easily performed with a stack. As one can see, the height and depth of the stack are properly captured by the `\hrule` boundary lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\hrule

\ooalign{\relax\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip-2ex}Q\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip+2ex}\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip+1ex}X\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip-1ex}%
        }%
\def\stacktype{L}
\stackunder[1ex]{\stackon[2ex]{}{Q}}{X}

\hrule
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 & thanks for this short solution just requiring 1 package.

Answer (score 1):

After reading [the answer of Heiko Oberdiek](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252003/6865), I understood (at least something of) the meaning of the original code.

After reading [the answer of Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252029/6865), I could simplify the original code to

```
\Longstack{%
           \raisebox{+2ex}{X}\cr%
           \raisebox{-1ex}{X}\cr%
           }
```

(with  package and configuration as in Steven B. Segletes' answer).

Just to get height and depth of this, also measuring the replacement

```
\raisebox{+2ex}{X}
\raisebox{-1ex}{X}
```

works, i.e.

```
\newlength\myHeight
\newlength\myDepth

\settoheight{\myHeight}{%
  \raisebox{+2ex}{\vphantom{X}}%
  \raisebox{-1ex}\vphantom{{X}}% this line only needed when this "lower X" 
                               % would reach higher than the "upper X"
}%

\settodepth{\myDepth}{%
  \raisebox{+2ex}{\vphantom{X}}% this line only needed when this "higher X"
                               % would reach deeper than the "lower X"
  \raisebox{-1ex}{\vphantom{X}}%
}%
```

where I added `\vphantom`s for the case when "XX" is wider than `\textwidth` (but neither "higher X" nor  "lower X" is wider).

Then

```
\hbox{\vrule\@height\myHeight%
                    \@depth\myDepth%
                    \@width\z@}
```

has height and depth of the `\ooalign{...}` (and width zero).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength\myHeight
\newlength\myDepth

\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\hrule
\ooalign{\relax\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip-2ex}{X}\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip+2ex}\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip+1ex}{X}\cr%
         \noalign{\vskip-1ex}%
        }% 
%
\settoheight{\myHeight}{%
  \raisebox{+2ex}{\vphantom{X}}%
  \raisebox{-1ex}\vphantom{{X}}% 
 }%
\settodepth{\myDepth}{%
  \raisebox{+2ex}{\vphantom{X}}%
  \raisebox{-1ex}{\vphantom{X}}%
 }%
\hbox{\vrule\@height\myHeight%
            \@depth\myDepth%
            \@width\z@}%
\hrule 

\makeatother 
\end{document}
```

resulting in this output:

[image: Result]

(which I would have never come to without the other two answers - thanks!).